# How to split a string variable into n variables in R

Tags: r, split

In R I need to split a string variable of a dataframe into n variables separated by "->" without knowing in advance the number of new variables to create

Comment: I need to create new variables in the dataframe
df$string is the original variable and I need to create df$var1...df$varN according to the sep "->" included in the df$string

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  Please share a small reproducible example

Comment: Home -> Section1 -> leaf -> prod
Scan -> Bill -> Doctor
Home

I would get Var1 to Var4 (without knowing in advance that I have 4 vars
Var1       Var2           Var3     Var4
Home     Section1    leaf       prod
Scan      Bill              Doctor
Home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` to get the split output in a `list`.

```
lst <- strsplit(df$string, "->")
```

and then `rbind` it after padding NA at the end if the `list` elements are of unequal `length`.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
```

---

If we need to split the columns into create additional columns, one option is `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, "string", "->")
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(string = c("some->thing->else", "some->thing"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```